# Issue viewing hebrew fonts in Chrome on Mac

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, unicode, right-to-left, hebrew

I'm having issues working with Hebrew characters on Chrome (v79) with Mac (10.13.4).

Some character combinations seem to be missing. For example, when trying to combine bet (`ב`) and qamats qatan (`ׇ`), I see two stacked boxes.

[image]

These two characters have code points of `1489` and `1479` [Derived from running`"{char}".codePointAt(0)`].

Funny thing is when I do this same thing in Firefox, I see the characters. And when I copy and paste these boxes into the Atom text editor, the proper characters appear.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out all you need to do is change the font in Chrome to one that fully captures the hebrew alphabet [or the alphabet you're targeting].

Here are the steps:

1. Open Chrome Main Menu
2. Click on *Settings*
3. Under *Appearance*, click on *Customize Fonts*
4. Under *Fixed-width font*, select a new font that captures your alphabet. You can see this [list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/05c7/fontsupport.htm) for a rundown. I chose *Courier New* just to test things, and now the characters appear properly. I also installed [Noto fonts](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) (Noto Sans Hebrew), and this worked as well.

Hope this is helpful if you happen to have this issue.